# Windows Server 2008 on a Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, windows-8, virtual-machines

I have a Windows 7 machine and I would like to make a virtual machine with Windows Server 2008 (and probably Windows Server 8 if possible) on it. The problem is that the Virual PC 2007 does not support Windows 7 as a host and Windows Virtual PC does not support Windows Server as a guest.

So what are my options here? I am a student and have access to free MS stuff in Dream Spark. Obviously I do not want to invest money in such a software and will prefer if the product is from MS.

For instance I know that Hyper-V exists as a standalone product, but I suppose it is still some sort of a server OS. However if I install it (or the whole Windows Server) will it be possible to host Windows 8 and Windows Server 8?

(Just to make it clear - I do not have the option to add another partition on my HDD:

- Windows 7
- Windows 8
- System Reserved
- Extended partition with logical partitions
  )

Comment: does VMWARE supports new flavor of windows? I haven't been looking into VMs for a while, but they always were the first to support new OS

Comment: If you do not have space on your hard disk, you won't be able to create a virtual machine, either.

Comment: **Virtual PC does not support Windows Server as a guest.** -- "does not support" is not the same thing as "does not work".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VirtualBox, https://www.virtualbox.org/, runs very well on Windows 7 and supports almost everything as a guest.

Comment: +1 It'll also run 64-bit guests if the host is 64-bit.

Comment: I can confirm that VirtualBox on a Win7 machine happily runs Server 2008 as a VM.